# Python: What is the best method to replace a string in a dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dictionary like this:

```
{('Live', '2017-Jan', '103400000', 'Amount'): 30, 
 ('Live', '2017-Feb', '103400000', 'Amount'): 31, 
 ('Live', '2017-Mar', '103400000', 'Amount'): 32,
 ('Live', '2017-Jan', '103401000', 'Amount'): 34
}
```

What is the best way to replace the 'Live' string with 'Live2' for all keys in the dictionary?

I tried already the following but it is throwing an error:

```
# cellset is the dictionary
for x in cellset:
    x.replace('Live','Live1')
```

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: You can’t really “replace” a key, you have to get a reference the value, delete the old key and reinsert the value with the new key.

Comment: Can you show an expected result of your operation using your example dictionary?

Comment: Moreover, consider that strings and tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {
    ('Live', '2017-Jan', '103400000', 'Amount'): 30, 
    ('Live', '2017-Feb', '103400000', 'Amount'): 31, 
    ('Live', '2017-Mar', '103400000', 'Amount'): 32,
    ('Live', '2017-Jan', '103401000', 'Amount'): 34
}

new_d = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    new_key = tuple('Live1' if el == 'Live' else el for el in k)
    new_d[new_key] = v

print(new_d)

# Output:
# {('Live1', '2017-Jan', '103400000', 'Amount'): 30, ('Live1', '2017-Feb', '103400000', 'Amount'): 31, ('Live1', '2017-Mar', '103400000', 'Amount'): 32, ('Live1', '2017-Jan', '103401000', 'Amount'): 34}
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have shown you how to create a new dictionary with 'Live' replaced by 'Live1'. If you want these replacement to take place in the original dictionary, a possible solution would look something like this

```
for (head, *rest), v in tuple(d.items()):
    if head == "Live":
        d[("Live1", *rest)] = v
        del d[(head, *rest)]
```